# TextFormField data disappear when closing the Key Board

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am building a flutter app, and I have a `Register` form there. I am using `TextFormFields` and below is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final borderColorGreen = const Color(0xff339966);

  TextEditingController nameTxtController =TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailTxtController =TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController mobileTxtController =TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordTxtController =TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController confirmPasswordTxtController =TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/background_login_5.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildTitleSection(),
            _buildInputFields("Name",nameTxtController),
            _buildInputFields("Email",emailTxtController),
            _buildInputFields("Mobile",mobileTxtController),
            _buildInputFields("Password",passwordTxtController),
            _buildInputFields("Confirm Password",confirmPasswordTxtController),
            _buildRegisterButton(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTitleSection() {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "something.xyz",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: borderColorGreen,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildInputFields(String label, TextEditingController textController) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, bottom: 20),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[

            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: textController,
                      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: label,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white30, width: 2.0),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }





  Widget _buildRegisterButton() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 20, left: 20),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
              child: SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity, // match_parent
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "Create Account",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                    ),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                    color: borderColorGreen,
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

When I click on a `TextField` the keyboard opens and I can type text. However if I press the **back button** of my phone to close the keyboard, then the text I entered  from all fields. 
I am referring to the hardware back button available in Android phones.

The form is scrllable and after entering text to a `TextField` if I clicked on the other `TextField`, the text stay there as it should. If I press the back button to close the keyboard, all text in the form is gone.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Shouldn't you see a down button instead of a back button when a keyboard is open?

Comment: @Amsakanna : I am talking about the back button in phone.

Comment: Please change the widget to `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: Ah! I see. You're talking about the hardware button. Nevertheless I tried your code in my phone (with software back button) and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @HemanthRaj: Yes, that was the issue. I did not convert the class into `StatefulWidget`, instead I made another class by extending the `StatefulWidget`. Please provide your comment as an answer, no code required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please change your widget to a `StatefulWidget`, that will not cause the controllers to reset.

Hope that helps!

Comment: My widget is stateful but the same issue?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanM.Elmarakby Were you able to sort this for stateful widgets? I am experiencing the same

Comment: I can't remember but I think it was because of the future builder

Answer (score 0):

Problem Explanation:
If a stateful widget is rebuilt, all widgets inside it rebuilds (including stateless)
 Closing the keyboard triggers rebuild.

Since you are initializing `new TextEditingController()` inside the stateless widget, it's getting re-initialized every time it rebuilds and hence you are losing the data

Solution 1: 
Convert to `Stateful Widget`

Solution 2: 
You can pass the `nameTxtController` as a parameter to the stateless widget

```
class RegisterPage extends StatelessWidget {

  RegisterPage({this.nameTxtController);
  TextEditingController nameTxtController;
  ...
```

Solution Explanation:
`Solution 1` works because Stateful Widgets holds your controller as it has it's own memory unlike Stateless Widgets.

`Solution 2` works because the parameter as reference and not re-initialized when it rebuilds